# Vimeo style drop content/slide down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to look at how best to try and create my own style of drop down/slide down (on hover) menu bar alike to the [Vimeo](http://www.vimeo.com) website which lowers all content below.

If any one can suggest the best method of approach as I am seeing both CSS3 and Jquery versions as well as some ajax ones and am not convinced which is the best method.

It seems to me that a type of accordion effect may be best, can anyone confirm if there is a plugin which can best suit my needs here.

Thanks.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You just need jQuery UI with hover intent, check [this out](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#hoverintent).

(Or maybe [jQuery UI menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/))